# OcamL lazy list series generating

Tags: ocaml, lazy-evaluation, lazylist

I've got a problem with this task:

- Define lazy list lSpec (Ocaml) that contains one 1, two 2, three 3 etc. 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,...

As far I have got:

```
type 'a llist = LNil | LCons of 'a * (unit -> 'a llist);;

let rec lfrom k = LCons (k, function () -> lfrom (k+1));; 

let rec ltake = function  
(0, _) -> []  
| (_, LNil) -> []  
| (n, LCons(x,xf)) -> x::ltake(n-1, xf()) ;;
```

This function is generating the series of integer based on input numer, eg.

```
ltake (5,lfrom 30);; 
- : int list = [30; 31; 32; 33; 34]
```

The thing that I want to do i to convert function lfrom to create not series of integers, but the series from my task. But I have no idea if there is some pattern to create such series?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have now uses just one value `k` to keep track of where it is in the sequence. Fundamentally this would be enough for the new problem, but using just one number for the state would make things difficult to keep track of.

You might consider something like:

```
let rec lspecfrom (j, k) = . . .
```

Where `j` is the number you're working on (1, 2, 3, 4, ...) and `k` is how many have been generated so far. Then the whole list would be generated by a call `lspecfrom (1, 0)`.

Comment: Should I use some matching or if instruction, because I still can't figure out a solution?

Comment: You should test the relative values of `j` and `k` (assuming you're following my suggestion). For that, you can use an `if` expression. (Note that `if` in OCaml is an expression with a value.)

Comment: Is there some way to set k value to zero in if expression while it was incremented to eg 3?

Comment: OCaml variables are immutable, so you don't set them. But when you make a recursive call you can pass any value you like.

Comment: Ok, i manage to do something like this: `let rec lspecfrom (j,k) = if (j>k) then LCons (j, function () -> lspecfrom (j,k+1)) else LCons (j+1, function () -> lspecfrom (j+1,1));;` It is working, but could you tell me if it looks ok? Thanks for help :)

Comment: This is hard to read but has exactly the right structure. The problem is simple enough that if it works the code is probably correct :-) I hope I didn't give away too much.